# ThenInclude не позволяет получить вложенность 3 и дальше уровня

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Примерно следующая структура классов:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id;
    public List<Order> Orders;
}

public class Order
{
    public Address Sender;
    public Address Recipient;
}

public class Address
{
    public Country Country;
}

public class Country
{
    public string Alpha2;
}
```

И есть некий метод, в котором необходимо получить данные из БД:

```
public async Task SomeMethod(string userId)
{
    User user = ApplicationDbContext.Users
        .Include(u => u.Orders)
            .ThenInclude(u => u.Sender) // Тут всё работает шикарно
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Country) // А вот тут всё ломается
                // Если быть чуть конкретнее, то IntelleSence предлагает
                // поля того же уровня вложенности как у Sender (в примере - Recipient)
                // А ошибка говорит, что User не содержит определения Country
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
    // Дальнейшая работа
}
```

Если я правильно понял материал [Загрузка связанных данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/related-data) от MicroSoft, то мой код должен работать.
Прошу указать на мою ошибку

**UPD:** Нашёл ошибку в собственном коде. Пример, написанный выше, абсолютно верный, и правильно компилируется.

Comment: раньше был такой баг в IntelliSence, но его вроде пофиксили в 2019 и 3.1, а какие версии вы используете и компилируется ли он через консоль `dotnet build`, т.к. ваш код валиден и у меня в vs code это работает https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237

Comment: @ExplodingKitten VS 2019 16.4.6 и .net core 3.1; Он точно не запускается в самой студии. Даже если вбить команду dotnet build, получается сообщение об 1 ошибке; Нашёл ошибку у себя в коде